# I'm trying to use Reactjs in Visual Studio Online

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, azure

I imported 'react-router-dom' in VSonline terminal and tried to use  to make SPA web-application. However, when I tried to render it by using 'npm start' in terminal, this error comes up..

[image: WebSocketError[1]]

I have to use visual studio online for some reason, and need to use react-router-dom. If anyone can hand a solution for this problem, it will give a big help to coding beginner :( ..

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer here. You have to change a line of code in node_modules:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59422598/7227686