# React "SecurityError: The operation is insecure." because of webpackHotDevClient in production?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, webpack, digital-ocean

I was in the process of deploying my very first React app to a custom set-up DigitalOcean droplet running Debian 10.
I serve (or at least try to) via nginx proxy that is fed by npm start process using pm2.

For production build:

```
npm run build
```

I started the server using

```
pm2 start npm -- start
```

Nginx is all up and running and can serve plain HTML files without a problem. HTTPS also works as it should.

Nginx server conf for HTTPS (in case it does matter):

```
server {
root /root/react-app-name;
index index.html;

server_name mysecretdomain.com www.mysecretdomain.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysecretdomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysecretdomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

access_log /var/log/nginx/mysecretdomain.com.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/mysecretdomain.com.error.log;
}
```

Nginx conf for HTTP (in case it does matter):

```
server {
if ($host = www.mysecretdomain.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}


if ($host = mysecretdomain.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

server_name mysecretdomain.com www.mysecretdomain.com;

return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Then I ran into the following error:

[FireFox SecurityError 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMkQJ.jpg)

[FireFox SecurityError 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2JXo.jpg)

Most of the answers I read only deal with it by changing a setting under about:config, but I also get an error message saying **"SecurityError: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS."** in Chrome and on any other devices/browsers I've tried.
So it is safe to say that it is NOT client-side.

I suppose it has to do with the *webpackHotDevClient* and that, for some reason, I still appear to be in development mode. I thought the build was supposed to be for production already?

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Did you find a resolution for this? I am running into the same thing

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of this issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59359280/react-app-error-failed-to-construct-websocket-an-insecure-websocket-connecti

Comment: @ChadJensen Unfortunately not, I settled for Gatsby for that particular project instead. I might run into the same issue again with another pure React project so I will keep you posted. However, user2875678's hint above looks promising.

Comment: I was able to resolve by downgrading react scripts to 3.2.0. It's not perfect, but it got me around the issue for now.