# Getting "Failed to construct WebSocket" error when deploying create-react-app to Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, websocket

When I try to deploy my site made with create-react-app to Heroku, I am getting the following error:

```
SecurityError: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS.
```

I have tried the steps in [#8079](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8079) but i am still getting the same issue.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React app error: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59359280/react-app-error-failed-to-construct-websocket-an-insecure-websocket-connecti)

Comment: This was actually the same solution mentioned in #8079, doesn't work for me.