# WebSocket error when React app is deployed

Tags: reactjs, websocket, deployment

I receive this error:

webpackHotDevClient.js:60 WebSocket connection to 'wss://{url}/sockjs-node' failed: ./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js

```
    {"name": "packspace",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@loadable/component": "^5.14.1",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

```
// Connect to WebpackDevServer via a socket.
var connection = new WebSocket(
  url.format({
    protocol: window.location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'wss' : 'ws',
    hostname: process.env.WDS_SOCKET_HOST || window.location.hostname,
    port: process.env.WDS_SOCKET_PORT || window.location.port,
    // Hardcoded in WebpackDevServer
    pathname: process.env.WDS_SOCKET_PATH || '/sockjs-node',
    slashes: true,
  })
);

// Unlike WebpackDevServer client, we won't try to reconnect
// to avoid spamming the console. Disconnect usually happens
// when developer stops the server.
connection.onclose = function () {
  if (typeof console !== 'undefined' && typeof console.info === 'function') {
    console.info(
      'The development server has disconnected.\nRefresh the page if necessary.'
    );
  }
};
```

Working in React app and the app is deployed to server. It is working normally on localhost but I am getting the error that above at the title when I enter the deployed URL with https or http. I checked the answer in [React app error: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59359280/react-app-error-failed-to-construct-websocket-an-insecure-websocket-connecti) but my file is already like that.

How can I fix that error?