# Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, package.json

I am deploying a React app but am getting a strange error when I visit the page over https.

When I visit the page over https I receive the following error:

`SecurityError: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS.`

Tried some of the solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59359280/react-app-error-failed-to-construct-websocket-an-insecure-websocket-connecti) but they didn't work.

I am including a copy of the package.json file. Let me know if you need me to upload any other parts of code to help debug.

Thanks in advance.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "magnus-ui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "history": "^5.3.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-awesome-button": "^7.0.4",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.6.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.8.0",
    "react-datepicker2": "^3.3.13",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.7.1",
    "react-json-editor-ajrm": "^2.5.13",
    "react-notifications-component": "^4.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-select": "^5.6.1",
    "url-join": "^5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: You must be opening a non TLS websocket on the page. W3C Security forbids this. You will have to upgrade both ends of the websocket to TLS.